# SwiftyJSON nil dictionary object Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, swifty-json

How do you retrieve a child dictionary element from firebase object if the child dictionary does not exist.

myDict is a

```
[String: String]
```

myDict: `jsonObj["dict_obj"].dictionaryValue`

says can not convert `[String: JSON]` to `[String:String]`

Comment: You'd probably have a lot fewer problems if you'd switch to Decodable.

Comment: sounds like you need to json.serialize your response before you try and retrieve the info

Comment: Thanks, decodable is not an option with this implementation (too much to go back and rewrite).  However, if I load up the object and then simply call firebase to return the dictionary for that object (if it exists) works and then simply assign the results to the parent object.  Don't like it but it does work